# How to authenticate user based on special condition in aws cognito

Tags: node.js, jwt, exchange-server, outlook-addin, amazon-cognito

[This is a follow up question of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58113245/aws-cognito-how-to-treat-request-as-authenticated-if-user-is-found-else-redirec)

Basically I want to authenticate user if certain condition passes.
This is basically like a no password flow.

In this flow, I have a jwt token issued by an exchange server.

If the jwt token is valid, then aws cognito should consider this request as authenticated and provide access token to use.

Refresh tokens are not needed as the jwt token issued by exchange server will act as refresh token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/implementing-passwordless-email-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/

Basically, the logic in Verify Auth Challenge trigger is changed.
here we need validate token provided by exchange server.
Aws cognito provides a good api to configure it properly.